# Parsing url using url-parse

Tags: javascript, parse-url

I am using [library to parse urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse) on my page:

```
import * as urlParse from 'url-parse';

const parseUrl = url => {
try {
 return urlParse(url);
} catch (e) {
 return null;
 }
};
```

The issue is when the url 'www.stackoverflow.com' is passed to the function, `parseUrl` returns `http:localhost\www.stackoverflow.com`

should I use to obtain the value `http://www.stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: `'www.stackoverflow.com'` isn't a URL.

Comment: it is acceptable value in our backend and so many other systems. please check this: https://www.regextester.com/94502

Comment: Why are you calling `parseUrl` recursively? This is an unending recursion

Comment: @Afflatus The library doesn't care what's acceptable in your backend or matched by some random pattern somebody posted online. It needs to be a string that doesn't cause an error when you pass it to `URL()`, that's how the library works.

Comment: you are right I fixed the name of the alias. still doesn't work

Comment: Unless you specify the protocol i.e. http/https, the parser will consider your first parameter as a relative path. The `baseUrl` parameter defaults to your browser `location` attribute and hence you have the localhost being prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any external lib for this:

```
const parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = '//www.stackoverflow.com';
console.log(`${parser.protocol}//${parser.hostname}`); // 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```

Comment: @ChrisG I don't see any result there. Try running it in console

Comment: @EugeneTsakh As Chris G states, you've made a relative link, therefore that code will just return the protocol and hostname of whatever page you run it on. If you change your `href` to `www.google.com` and run it in Stack Overflow's console, it will still log `https://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: I see. Than use parser.href = '//www.stackoverflow.com';

Comment: @ChrisG Do not edit an answer/code to highlight its shortcomings, as edits should be reserved for positive change and/or clean-up rather than making an answer objectively worse. In this case, a comment is sufficient.